# Javascript return true if a value exists in a nested array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to return true if a nested array contains a particular value

In this example I'm trying to see if the users array has the current users id but I get the object instead of `true`

```
var currentUserId ="MBsCLlPbilRr26Jpz5oxhMULRvC2"
var users = [
  {
    id: "MBsCLlPbilRr26Jpz5oxhMULRvC2",
    name: "Dennis",
    url: undefined,
  },
  {
    id: "CLlPbhMULRvC2jnjnDe",
    name: "Dennis",
    url: undefined,
  },
]
console.log(users.find(user=>user.id === currentUserId))
```

Comment: Use `.some()` instead of `.find()`

Comment: you want `some()` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are using .find() instead of .some(). Try the following:

```
var currentUserId ="MBsCLlPbilRr26Jpz5oxhMULRvC2"
var users = [
  {
    id: "MBsCLlPbilRr26Jpz5oxhMULRvC2",
    name: "Dennis",
    url: undefined,
  },
  {
    id: "CLlPbhMULRvC2jnjnDe",
    name: "Dennis",
    url: undefined,
  },
]
console.log(users.some(user=>user.id === currentUserId))
```

The difference is in the output. .find() will return the value, .some() will return a boolean.